# Not able to make a POST call using JAX-RS in RAD using Websphere

Tags: java, rest, websphere

I'm trying to test a restful call using RESTClient for a POST CALL.. All it throws is

```
[9/7/16 8:29:04:692 AST] 00000080 RequestProces I org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor logException The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (405) with message 'null' while processing GET request sent to http://localhost:9080/Test/rest/test/add
```

Here is my sample code

```
  public class TestClient {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try { 
        testWebService(); 
    } catch (ClientWebException loClientWebEx) { 
        loClientWebEx.printStackTrace(); 
        System.out.println("Response Status :- " + loClientWebEx.getResponse().getStatusCode()); 
        System.out.println("Response Message :- " + loClientWebEx.getResponse().getMessage()); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

}

private static void testWebService() {
    try { 
        String lsUrl = "http://localhost:9080/Test/rest/test/add"; 
        RestClient client = new RestClient();
        System.out.println("URL is : " + lsUrl); 
        Resource resource = client.resource(lsUrl);
        JSONObject loJSON = new JSONObject(); 
        loJSON.put("Number1", 54321); 
        loJSON.put("Number2", 12345); 
        System.out.println("JSON input::"+loJSON);

        resource.get().getStatusType();

        StatusType response = resource.get().getStatusType();
        System.out.println("The response is:");
        System.out.println(response); 
    } catch (ClientWebException loClientWebEx) { 
        loClientWebEx.printStackTrace(); 
        System.out.println("Response Status :- " + loClientWebEx.getResponse().getStatusCode()); 
        System.out.println("Response Message :- " + loClientWebEx.getResponse().getMessage()); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }


}
}
```

### Web.xml

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>Test</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>com.rest.HelloWorldConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>REST</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### Code

```
   @Path("/test")
public class TestClass {

public static final String RESP_CD_OK = "200";
public static final String RESP_CD_ACCEPTED = "202";
public static final String RESP_CD_ERROR = "500";
public static final String RESP_CD_SERVER_ERROR = "503";

public static final String RESPONSE_CD = "response_cd";
public static final String RESPONSE_MESSAGE = "response_msg";

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public TestClass() {
}

/**
 * 
 * @param foJSONObject
 * @return
 */
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/add")
public JSONObject addNumbers(JSONObject foJSONObject) {
    long llNo1;
    long llNo2;

    JSONObject loResJSONObject = new JSONObject();

    try {

        llNo1 = (Long) foJSONObject.get("Number1");
        llNo2 = (Long) foJSONObject.get("Number2");

        long llResult = llNo1 + llNo2;

        loResJSONObject.put(RESPONSE_CD, RESP_CD_OK);
        loResJSONObject.put("Result", llResult);
        loResJSONObject.put(RESPONSE_MESSAGE, "Numbers added successfully");

    } catch (Exception loException) {

        loException.printStackTrace();

        loResJSONObject.put(RESPONSE_CD, RESP_CD_ERROR);
        loResJSONObject.put("Result", "-1");
        loResJSONObject.put(RESPONSE_MESSAGE,
                "Error: While adding numbers: " + loException.getMessage());
    }
    return loResJSONObject;

}

}
```

Is there anything missing from my side?

Comment: You say POST, but `while processing GET request sent to http://localhost:9080/Test/rest/test/add`

Comment: Thats what I'm confused. I've mentioned as POST in the service

Comment: I tried even that.. Its not showing the exact response

Comment: tried what?  What is `resource` anyway?  Where are the javadocs?

Comment: Its working fine, when I make the call using POSTMAN CLIENT.. When I run it as Java application to test in IDE, it throws the error

Comment: What I am suggesting is that `resource.get()` is the wrong method call for a `POST` - maybe there is a `resource.post()` ?  I don't know because I do not know what library you are using

Comment: I've tried as post too as by setting .. resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
   ClientResponse response = resource.post(loJSON); Now the error it throws is [9/7/16 9:54:49:553 AST] 00000077 RequestProces I org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor logException The following error occurred during the invocation of the handlers chain: WebApplicationException (415 - Unsupported Media Type) with message 'null' while processing POST request sent

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've solved it. Here is the updated code

```
resource.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
ClientResponse response = resource.post(loJSON);
```